# Iterate over HTML tags

Tags: java, android, android-ion

I am developing some kind of RSS application: the app downloads the content provided by a RSS feed and shows it to the user.

The post's content has tags like *p*, *img* and *h2*, I want to iterate (in order) over them and create **TextView**'s and **ImageView**'s depending of the tag.

For example, I want to show this HTML code:

```
<body>
    <h2>Some text</h2>
    <img src="image1.jpg">
    <p>A lot of text</p>
</body>
```

as

```
<TextView />
<ImageView />
<TextView />
```

I think [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is an option, but I am not sure how to use it or if Android includes a native solution.

I also want to incorporate lacy download for images, and I've found the [Ion library](https://github.com/koush/ion), but maybe for my use there are more simple solutions

**EDIT**:

As @Vogabe suggested, I am iterating over the tags using Jsoup. This is the code, maybe someone can find it useful

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(htmlContent);
Elements elements = document.getAllElements();

for (Element element:elements) {
    Tag tag = element.tag();

    if (tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSoup is a good solution for parsing HTML pages and retrieving data from it. The `Select()` method just accepts a css selector and will return the html elements that comply with that selector.

These 2 links should get you started:

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation

There are other parsers out there, but I do not have experience with them.
JSoup is widely adopted and very easy to use.